# Drupal 7.x + Ubercart 3.x + Domain Access

Tags: ubercart, multi-sites, domain-access, subsites

I have a full working Drupal 7 with Ubercart 3 running fine. It is well configured with thousands of products in it. I would like to create a sub-domain where all the contents and users are the same, but some things (theme, views, ubertcart) are configured differently. 
Domain Access module seemed to be the best way to acomplish my goal (it can handle differnt views, settings, themes, etc), but there is no such an option for Ubercart.

So, my problem is that I can not set different configuration on my subdomain for my Ubercart.

My questions are:
 - Is there any way to force Ubercart to use maybe an other db prefix, where Im storing the different settings.
 - Is there any other solution (other module) to my multisite problem?

Any help, tip or suggestion is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no working UC_domain module for Ubercart 3 - Drupal 7, and many issues of configuration - including payment methods per domain user are not availble

Comment: Yes, my final workaround is to have two drupal installs in the same db, but with different prefixes and share the common tables. I had to be careful, but now its just working fine.